# C++: Change variables captured in lambda from outside

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17

Is there any way to change the variable captured *by copy* in a lambda from the outside?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x = 3;
    auto f = [x]() { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
    // is there anything I can do here to make f print 4?
    f();
}
```

If this is possible, it feels really dirty. Is there a compelling reason why I shouldn't even think about doing so?

Comment: Probaly you should think about alternatives. Capture `x` by reference, make it a function parameter or don't use lambdas, use a class with overloaded `operator()` and `x` setter.

Comment: "*Is there a compelling reason why I shouldn't even think about doing so?*" Because it makes no sense? Because if you ever feel that you need to do so, then a lambda is the *wrong tool* for whatever job you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, no it is not possible to change local variables of a function/functor (which is what lambda is) from the outside.

Think of lambda as "regular" functions whose name you don't have. Just like for regular functions you can't change local variable values from the outside (params passed by value), you can't do it with lambda too. This is a necessary requirement for security & predictability of the result.

If you have a problem where you need to do this, as others have suggested use `[&]` syntax.

(There exists https://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs588.w14/static/stack_smashing.pdf but I think that relies on knowledge of compiler/system implementation and usually gets into undefined behaviour)

Comment: Along with the function having no name, the captured value is [unnamed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), which makes it impossible to refer to except from within the lambda's body.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 3;
    auto f = [&x]() { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
    x++;
    f();
}
```

Comment: I should have clarified that. I am aware of capturing by reference - the question is about changing the variable that was copied into the closure.

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine though - the answer was technically correct for the way the question was originally asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct do_nothing{ template<class...Args> void operator()(Args&&...)const{}};
template<class...cmd>
struct maybe_run_t;
template<> struct maybe_run_t<>:do_nothing{};
template<class cmd>struct maybe_run_t<cmd>{
  cmd&& value;
  template<class...Args>
  void operator()(Args&&...args)const{
    value(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
template<class...Args>
maybe_run_t<Args...> maybe_run(Args&&...args){
  return {std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

Then:

```
int x = 3;
auto f = [x](auto&&...cmd)mutable { maybe_run(cmd...)(x); std::cout << x << std::endl; };
// is there anything I can do here to make f print 4?
f([](auto&x){x=4;});
f();
```

Prints `4\n4\n`.

You have an optional argument.  If you pass one, it gets to modify `x`.  If you do not, the code works.

You could also do flow control based on its existence or return value.

Comment: IOW you're giving the lambda an argument , and in the lambda body, modify x based on the argument.

Comment: @m.m optional argument

Answer (score 0):

Revert back to the original 'lambda' type: create a struct or class with an operator()

```
struct myLambda
{
    int x;
    myLambda(int x) : x(x) {};
    operator() { std::cout << x << '\n'; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++14, you can do this:

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    auto l = [x]()mutable->decltype(auto){
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
        return (x);
    };
    l() = 42;
    l();
}
```

Actually, it's pretty easy to do something similar also in C++11:

```
auto l = [x]()mutable->decltype(x)&{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return x;
};
```

That is, you can modify the variable captured by copy simply by returning it by reference.

Comment: This works in your example but it requires actually executing the function in order to change the variable.